# When I run $.get in jQuery I receive "object Object". Why? What does mean exactly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm beginning in jQuery. I try to send an object through an AJAX request to my server but I receive `object Object`. What does it mean? Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var endereco = "http://localhost:8082/teste/get.php?";
    $("#btnentrar").on('click', function() {
        var formulario = $("#formulario").serialize();
        var get = $.get(endereco + "&acao=teste&" + formulario, function(data) {
            alert(get);
        });
    });

    $("#configuracao").on('click', function() {
        activate_subpage("#subpagina");
        $("#formulario").hide();
    });
    $("#avancarconfig").on('click', function() {
        $(location).attr('href', 'index.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: `get` is a promise, not the data you are expecting. Suggest you study some tutorials and the documentation for `$.get`. The docs even have examples

Answer (score 1):

The data returned by your php is contained in the `data` variable in the success callback of $.get():

```
$.get(endereco + "&acao=teste&" + formulario, function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```